# Rotating around z-axis in Blender does not convert to y-axis in GLTF-export

Tags: animation, gltf

I have a scene with a door in it. There is an animation on the door to open it. I want to use the scene in ThreeJS so I export it in GLTF (.glb specifically) format. The problem is, that the Z-axis in Blender is the y-axis in ThreeJS. I do have the option "+Y up" enabled during export. However, that somehow does not seem to work for the export of the animation. When I play the animation, the object all of a sudden flip and rotate around the ThreeJS-version of the z-axis.
Zip with the .blend and .glb files: https://we.tl/t-8hiGgS9rsY

You can use the glb-file here to see the animation: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Is there something I can do to make this animation work?

Comment: If you are still seeing this problem on the latest version of Blender, then I think it is a software bug in the exporter. Could you file an issue on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO?

Comment: I guess I could have edited my question later. I already filed a bug report there and it indeed is an issue in the exporter. Someone wrote a patch for it though didn't turn it into an MR it seems.
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1330